# .Net 6 json array into Generic type binding

Tags: asp.net-core, binding, .net-6.0

I have model like the one below:

```
public class MyClass{

   public string propertyOne {get;set}
   public SParameter<ComplexTypeClass> ComplexType{ get; set; }
   
   public MyClass(){
       ComplexType = new SParameter<ComplexTypeClass>(true,null);
   }
}
public class ComplexTypeClass{
  public string propertyTwo {get;set;}
  public int propertyThree {get;set;}
}
public class SParameter<Type>{

   public bool Visible { get; set; }
   public Type Value { get; set; }

   public SParameter() {

        
    }

    public SParameter(bool visible, Type value)
    {
        Visible = visible;
        Value = value;
    }
    public SParameter(Type value)
    {
        Visible = true;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

With .Net Framework in a Post ajax call i could pass the parameters in the way below:

```
{
"propertyOne":"blabla",
"Generals.Value.propertyTwo" : "test",
"Generals.Value.propertyThree" : 22,

}
```

Now with .net 6 if i pass a json like this the binder fill me only propertyOne and leave Generals.Value = null.

My target is to avoid to change the json body. There is no other way than to implement a custom model binder?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, i think you may need check your json and model. If it actually pass to backend successfully, you may make mistakes. Because model binding system bind the data by name,  your model property `public SParameter<ComplexTypeClass> ComplexType{ get; set; }` name is `ComplexType` but your json property name is `Generals.xxxxx`. It should be `ComplexType.xxxxxxx` or change `public SParameter<ComplexTypeClass> Generals{ get; set; }`. Please check.

Then your content type is application/json, you need custom JsonConverter instead of model binder. Custom model binder accepts form data(e.g. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(CustomJsonConverter))]
public class MyClass
{
    public string propertyOne { get; set; }
    public SParameter<ComplexTypeClass> ComplexType { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {                                                 
                                                           //change here....
        ComplexType = new SParameter<ComplexTypeClass>(true, new ComplexTypeClass());
    }
}
public class ComplexTypeClass
{
    public string propertyTwo { get; set; }
    public int propertyThree { get; set; }
}
public class SParameter<Type>
{
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public Type Value { get; set; }

    public SParameter()
    {
    }

    public SParameter(bool visible, Type value)
    {
        Visible = visible;
        Value = value;
    }
    public SParameter(Type value)
    {
        Visible = true;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Custom JsonConverter:

```
public class CustomJsonConverter: JsonConverter<MyClass>
{
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer,
                       MyClass value,
                       JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        //serialize to json
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WriteString("propertyOne", value.propertyOne);
        writer.WriteString("ComplexType.Value.propertyTwo", value.ComplexType.Value.propertyTwo);
        writer.WriteNumber("ComplexType.Value.propertyThree", value.ComplexType.Value.propertyThree);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
    public override MyClass Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
                             Type typeToConvert,
                             JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        //deserialize to model...
        var model = new MyClass();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                string propertyName = reader.GetString();
                reader.Read();
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "propertyOne":
                        var propertyOne = reader.GetString();
                        model.propertyOne = propertyOne;
                        break;
                    case "ComplexType.Value.propertyTwo":
                        var propertyTwo = reader.GetString();
                        model.ComplexType.Value.propertyTwo = propertyTwo;
                        break;
                    case "ComplexType.Value.propertyThree":
                        int propertyThree = reader.GetInt32();
                        model.ComplexType.Value.propertyThree = propertyThree;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public MyClass Test([FromBody]MyClass model)
{
    //do your stuff....
    return model;
}
```

Test in Postman:

[image]